# How to reverse the characters in a word in a string (c++)

Tags: c++, string, recursion

I have to reverse the string "Cat is running" to "running is Cat" for an assignment using a recursive function. I was able to reverse the entire string but the words themselves are backward, comes out as "gninnur si taC". How do I fix this? Did I just do my recursion function wrong or is their another step I'm missing? thanks! (Using only recursive function)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string Reverse(string str,string strCopy, int end, int start)
{   
    if (str[start] != '\0')
    {
        strCopy[end]=str[start];
        return Reverse(str, strCopy, end - 1, start + 1);
    }
    else { return strCopy; }    
}

int main()
{
    string str = "Cat is running";
    string strCopy = str;
    int start = 0;
    int end = str.length()-1;
    cout <<Reverse(str, strCopy, end, start) << endl;   
}
```

Comment: It seems that you aim is to reverse the order of the words, not the characters. In this case, consider delimiting your input string using a tokenizer such as `strtok`

Comment: I have not learned that yet, so I'm not allowed to use it. Is there any other way?

Comment: Sure, a simple way is to just add the string to a `std::istringstream`, read the words into a vector, reverse the vector with `std::reverse`, and write the words out again.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it with only recursive functions?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is like this:

```
recursive_reverse_words(input):
  if (input has one word or empty) return input
  first_word, rest = split(input)
  return recursive_reverse_words(rest) + " " + first_word
```

you need to write the split function.

Comment: What would the split function do? also my assignment says i can only use recursive functions

Comment: split will return the first word and the rest of a multi world phrase. You can write this recursively as well.

Comment: Well, that's a lot of allocation, and string-copying. Also, it's not tail-recursive.

Comment: Yes if your concern is performance don't use recursion in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first the algorithm:

1. Reverse the string.
2. Find words.

   1. Reverse them.

Reversing a string is quite simple, even if you are condemned to use recursion:

```
template <class BidiIter>
void reverse(BidiIter first, BidiIter last) {
    if (first == last || first == --last) return;
    std::iter_swap(first, last);
    reverse(++first, last);
}
```

Reversing *only* the words in themselves is slightly more tricky:

```
template <class BidiIter>
void reverse_words_only(BidiIter first, BidiIter last) {
    if (first == last) return;
    const auto pred = [](unsigned char c){ return isspace(c); };
    const auto begin = std::find_if_not(first, last, pred);
    const auto end = std::find_if(begin, last, pred);
    reverse(begin, end);
    reverse_words_only(end, last);
}
```

Next, using that for reversing a string word-for-word:

```
template <class BidiIter>
void reverse_words(BidiIter first, BidiIter last) {
    reverse(first, last);
    reverse_words_only(first, last);
}
```

Everything nicely tail-recursive. You might have to write a recursive version of `std::find_if()` and `std::find_if_not()` though.

Comment: Those are only tail-recursive if no destructor needs to be invoked after the recursive call, and you need that for the iterators (if they're not plain pointers) and the lambda object.

Comment: @molbdnilo The lambda is stateless, so no need. The iterators may be a point though, even if nearly all bidi-iterators are trivial.